# Gitlab - User Cannot see Private Project Under the Group

Tags: git, gitlab

Team,

In GitLab Community Edition v16.1.0 - I've create a project under Private Group in GitLab and then created a user with Developer role. However, when I login with the created user I cannot see the target project but I see the path of the group and subgroups. Also, I see show there's a project under the target subgroup but when I click on projects, it shows nothing.

grp-abc
subgrp-abc1
subgrp-abc2
project-abc3

I had created similar structure in gitlab v15 and it worked. I tried reading the articles/updates on v16 but didn't find anything interesting.

Just to verify, I had created a test project under a group and granted a Developer permission to a user. But still the user is failing to see the project.

Can anybody of you help me?

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you try to go directly to the URL of the project?

Comment: the project url is throwing 404 however the group url is working. When I hit the project url in separate browser (where in admin user already logged) I see it. Yesterday, we have tested this on v15 and it was working as expected